# Swift - Transition NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to code 2 ViewControllers, with different Navigation Bar aspects.

The main VC has a red NavigationBar, and I would like the second to be white.

I tried to use viewWillAppear() and viewWillDisappear() on my first ViewController but the result is not very good...

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = smoothRed
  navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = smoothRed    
  UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
  navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
}
```

[image]

The transition is very ugly...

I would like to have something like that:

[image]

Do you know how I could do?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to animate `false` like this when pushing the view controller:

```
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: false)
```

Comment: I would like to keep the transition effect (as you can see on the second picture)

Answer (score 0):

Laura, in the storyboard, did you add navigation controller as Embed in your controller?

If not, try to. Then, in your view did load, you can do `self.navigationController.backgroundColor = UIColor.red`